# How do i fix raid0 GPT partition table?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, gpt

hi i currently have two 1TB hdds in raid0 and I've noticed that Microsoft's diskpart has misaligned them. i don't have expertise in raid and don't know how to fix this problem. using testdisk i get mismatched track/sector and head/cylinder errors. and GParted gives

> invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sda

and

> The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately due to my reckless actions the data is irrecoverable so there is no longer a need for further discussion on the matter.

let's close it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have used motherboard-based software RAID (aka "fake RAID") under Windows but are trying to access the "raw" disks under Linux. If you use software RAID in one OS, you *must* use the *same* type of software RAID under *all* your OSes. You should consult documentation on this subject for Linux. For Ubuntu and related distributions, [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) may be helpful. If you're using Fedora, Gentoo, OpenSUSE, or something else, some details may differ, and you may want to track down relevant documentation for your specific distribution.